# React state not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component like this:

```
const students: [
  {id: '', name: '', age: '', attendance: ''}
  //... 1000 entries
]



class Students extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      studentID: 1
    }
  }



  createMonthlyChart = () => {
    const { studentID } = this.state
    let computeScore = students.attendance.map (
      item => {
        //... get attendance by id
      }
    )

    return chartData
  }

  handleOnChange = value => {
    console.log(value) // student key

    this.setState({
      studentID: value
    })

    this.createMonthlyChart() // not working
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        // ant design component
        <Select
          defaultValue={type}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
        >
        students.map((student, key) => (
          <Option key={student.id}> {student.name} </Option>
        ))
        </Select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

That is the just idea

I am not sure if I am using setState wrongly but somehow I get unexpected value

For example, the first time I click on a student, I don't get any chart visualization even though the data is there, I have to press it second time to get any chart.

And If I click on student without any attendance, I get empty chart after that for all students. I have to refresh the page to restart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Consider passing `studentID` as a parameter into `createMonthlyChart` rather than relying on state.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like you don't need the studentID state at all, you could directly call this.createMonthlyChart passing the value as a parameter to the function.
But if you need it for some other reason you can invoke that function as a callback to the setState like this:

```
this.setState({
  studentID: value
}, this.createMonthlyChart)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of things

The option should have the value

```
<option key={student.id} value={student.id}> {student.name}</option>
```

createMonthlyChart, should be called after updating the state (second parameter)

And you should use *event.target.value*

```
handleOnChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    studentID: event.target.value,
  }, this.createMonthlyChart);
};
```

And for the first time, you can use *componentDidMount*

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.createMonthlyChart();
}
```

And don't forget to initialize the state with the first student, like this

```
this.state = {
  studentID: students[0].id,
};
```